# Excel 2010 Remove Duplicate Value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have the below list of data and in this Login ID is unique. What I need a formula for is deleting any duplicate entries for the day and replacing it based on logout time.

```
Login ID Extn   Login   Logout  Date
16054   53051   10:00   14:00   27/08/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:30   29/08/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   31/08/2016
16054   53051   8:00    10:33   1/09/2016
16054   53051   10:33   16:00   1/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    18:00   2/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    17:04   5/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   6/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:04   7/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   8/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    15:30   9/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:30   12/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    14:58   14/09/2016
16054   53051   14:58   16:00   14/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   15/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   16/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    18:02   19/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    8:22    20/09/2016
16054   53051   8:22    13:31   20/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    17:00   26/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   27/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    16:00   28/09/2016
16054   53051   8:00    8:32    30/09/2016
16054   53051   8:32    8:33    30/09/2016
```

So to be more precise I have the below scenario where I have 2 entries for the same person on same day. One if the first time they logged in and the second entry is last time of logout. Now I want to check and delete the duplicate dates and just combine the two lowest of login times and highest of logout times.

```
16054   53051   8:00    8:22    20/09/2016
16054   53051   8:22    13:31   20/09/2016
```

And the result I want is as below:

```
16054   53051   8:00    13:31    20/09/2016
```

Can you please suggest me a formula for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is probably using a pivot table:

- select your data and go to: insert - pivot table
- drag "login ID", "extn" and "date" columns to "*rows*"
- drag "login" and "logout" to "*values*"
- click the small drop-down icon of "login" in "*values*" part - value field settings - select *min* and OK
- do the same for "logout"
- your "login" and "logout" will likely loose their number formatting, just select them in the pivot table and set number formatting to "time" (or custom, and enter format string: "hh:mm"
- go to pivot table settings - design and format your table as you need (remove subtotals, select report layout...)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try this but does not eliminate the duplicates for same day and just picks up the first value for the day. This does not solve my issues.

Comment: It works for me as in the screenshot. Doesn't it the same fire you? Do you need different output?